# Will the Garmin Edge Touring store an in progress ride if power is lost?

Tags: gps, garmin, battery

A rider is on a long ride, using a Garmin Edge Touring GPS unit and takes a break. If they wish to save battery on the Garmin, can they power it off and continue the same ride later?

I believe the Edge Touring is the same as the 810, with some features turned off.

Comment: Dunno - but do find some effective reminder to turn it back on.  You'll lose at least 10 km, and at least once.

Comment: @Criggie I don't follow

Comment: I think @Criggie is suggesting that when turning the Garmin off, if you don't have some sort of reminder to yourself, you'll forget to turn it back on. His suggestion is that it will be 10km before you remember, and it (forgetting to turn it on) will happen to you more than once.

Comment: I see. Very probably true :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Yes

A comment below made me wonder could a planned turn off be different to a random turn off like my original answer below.

So a quick test this morning and... 
if you turn it off through the button on the side when you turn it back on you will have the Discard and Save option. 
Press home, navigate to the trip screen again and your ride is ready to resume, just press the start button again.

If the Garmin decides to turn itself off though the data stored before that is lost.

---

Old answer... Proved to be incorrect

### Not without some manual steps

You will need to manually stop the ride by pressing the start/stop button, then save the ride from the options presented, before turning of the Garmin.

Then turn the Garmin back on before riding off.

You will then be able to stitch the GPS files together to make one continuous journey if you don't want your ride broken into multiple sections

If the power turns off mid ride that section of the ride is lost.

I know this because my Touring turned itself off a few weeks ago mid ride and I lost the first 5km of my ride.

Comment: @barry no problem. How long will you be riding for because it easily has battery for 8 hours

Comment: I have a 100 mile ride on the back burner. However, I've discovered I can charge it with a portable charger whilst using it so should be ok

Comment: I don't think this is generally true. I have an Edge 810, which should be almost identical, and I've accidentally turned it off mid-ride more than once. When I turned it on again it continued right where it left off, minus any terrain I covered while it was off.

Comment: @CareyGregory you are correct just tested this morning . Must have been because mine was an unexpected shut down. Have updated my answer

Comment: @barry sorry Barry seems i gave you wrong information. I have updated my answer

Comment: Thanks @CearonO'Flynn. Out of interest, why did yours turn itself off? Battery dead?

Comment: @barry not 100% sure but it was raining a lot and my USB port cover may not have been fully closed. Battery hasn't died on mine yet and I've done a few 100 mile plus on it where it got to about 30-40% with navigation on.

Comment: @CearonO'Flynn you must ride fast :-)

Comment: @barry about 6 and a half hours or so

Comment: I've shut down my 810 and my 1000 several times and it always just picks of where I've left it. Always, except for one time. I stopped for pizza, paused the recording and the auto-timer eventually powered down my 810. When I restarted it there was no trace what so ever of my ride. 

So, if it's an important ride I would stop it and save it before shutting the unit down. Better to have several chopped up tracks than one that is just the last part.